# Undefined form passed to ng-submit in Modal (UI Bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, validation, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement  `modal` validation. I am using `controller as modal` syntax. Close and submit function are working as expected. Unfortunately validation not. loginForm which is passed to controller submit function is `undefined`! Because of this issue i can't perform username input validation.

```
<form form="loginForm" class="registerModal"  ng-submit="modal.submit(loginForm)" novalidate> 
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">TITLE</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body ">
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username:<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="modal.user.username" ng-maxlength="3" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  uib-alert class="col-sm-offset-4 alert-danger" ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Error Msg</div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="modal.showErrors=true">Register</button>
        <button class="btn pull-left" type="button" ng-click="modal.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller.js

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('RegistrationCtrl',['$uibModalInstance', function ($uibModalInstance) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.showErrors = false;

    //Modal
    vm.user = {
       username: 'default'
    };
    */
    /**********Submiting form**********/
    vm.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    vm.submit = function(form){
        console.log('submiting....');
        console.log(form);  //it is undefined
    };

}]);
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `form form="loginForm"`, it should be `form name="loginForm"`:

```
<form name="loginForm" class="registerModal" ng-submit="modal.submit(loginForm)" novalidate>
```